# Automation issue with MOS and UiAutomator

Tags: android-uiautomator

I am using the following command in APK to invoke UiAutomator based test scripts:

```
proc = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("uiautomator runtest Library.jar -c com.uia.example.my.Library");
```

It is working fine till LOS.
But in MOS, I am getting the following error:

> Unable to unlink
>   /data/local/tmp/dalvik-cache/arm64/sdcard@data@Library.jar@classes.dex:
>   Permission denied

Please provide solution for this issue.

Note: I need to run scripts in release binary. So rooting is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Android Testing Support Library** and create a test case extending `InstrumentationTestCase` as explained in [Testing UI for Multiple Apps](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html).

Then run your tests using

```
$ ./gradlew connectedCheck
```

Comment: How to run tests within mobile, Without PC connectivity. Is it possible to invoke tests from Test APK?

Comment: This post (http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2011/09/android-testing-running-tests-from-code.html) may give you some ideas about how to run tests from application.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to no write permission in /data/local/tmp/ where you placed your Library.jar file. Write permission is required to extract dex from the Jar.

May be OEMs could disable rooting and  remove write permission to /data/local/tmp and that may the reason for your issue in production/release builds ..

If you use uiautomator commands like : uiautomator runtest Library.jar ....
uiautomator will search for Library.jar by default in /data/local/tmp . 
You can check uiautomator shell script present in /system/bin.
export run_base=/data/local/tmp   ==> Classpath for searching the dex files.

One solution could be to place Library.jar and modified uiautomator script in your application folder (data/data//files).
you have to modify run_base with your application data folder path.

You can bundle the uiautomator script and jar following the instrcutions in below link :
http://gimite.net/en/index.php?Run%20native%20executable%20in%20Android%20App

Hope it helps ... Please update about your results.

Comment: This is perfect solution. Thanks Suraj